# Tunnel Postgresql traffic through a webserver

Tags: postgresql, ssh, cloud-foundry, tunnel

I have the following scenario and wonder if this is even possible.
I have two apps in different cloud foundry environments:

- app1 (env1)
- app2 (env2)

I have two postgresql db´s in those environments.

- db1 (env1)
- db2 (env2)

---

- The apps are only reachable via port 443 and 80 over nat-ip´s.
- The db´s are not reachable from outside and can only be reached through the apps in those environments.

---

Can I somehow create a tunnel to those db´s through the webserver of the given apps?
So that for example on **app1** I can reach **db2** by accessing **url.app2.com/pgsql** ?

My ultimate goal would be:
**app1** creates backup of **db1** and pipes it directly to **db2** to restore it. And that through the webserver.
I got this already successfully working tunneling over localhost.

Comment: Is db2 and db1 in the same region?  I mean is the db2 exposed the accessing to the network of app1?   Maybe you can this first.

Comment: No, only app1 can access db1 and only app2 can access db2.

Comment: Basically,  it's the IaaS side provide the HA between 2 regions.  Looks like Hyper-scaler PG have this functionality. But they still are in the same region.

But for your scenario,  maybe you can expose some extra internal API in app2 for app1 to pipe?

Comment: Is that really possible via an API? Do you know of some example projects in that direction? I find it little bit hard to imagine how this works.

Comment: via one or several API,  is just provide Datasource-> Datasource (piping all the data). It's possible.  But you will meet many traps.  You need calculate the "Delta" data between the source and target datasource.

e.g. In app2,  expose below API
pipe(String tableName,  List<> rows)

We need calculate the real data which want to be updated/added.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the input. I´ll definitely check it out.